# What factors should I consider when selecting a Web-service framework?

Tags: web-services, delphi

I want to build my first Web-service capability, and I see several ways in Delphi XE to do this ... WebBroker, WebSnap, WebServices, Indy.
I set up an Apache server and the Echo demo which shows one possible architecture/framework, but have read that using WebBroker may allow taking Apache out of the loop.

I need simplicity, and some scalability, but only a few clients typically, up to 20 max.

How does one begin to select an approach, an approach that can be supported in Delphi for around 10 years from now?
I'm new to Web programming, but been using Delphi/TP since the beginning.
Any advice from the veterans?

Comment: If load is not large you can go multithreading (like OmniThreadingLibrary) + blocking simple sockets like Ararat Synapse.
You can integrate it all into IIS or Apache to you taste. After that you would need to install caching reverse-proxy like nginx or lighttpd - thouse that would exchange multiple long-lasting connections on outer borderline for few fast short one to the inner side. I suggest to to read about nginx - http://wiki.nginx.org/Main - if C10K problem is what i might met though in lesser scale. Twice so if those image are static, never changing files, then nginx may be right tool

Comment: If you need hi-load dynamic services in pure Delphi, then i suggest you quick scan of latest flames around DataSnap reliability. DataSnap was build around Indy and suffers from aforementioned c10K problem in ultimate form. As a bonus there were enlisted few alternatives. One of those is Synopse (not Synapse) mORMot project, that talks directly with http.sys and probably provides least possible resource usage for HTTP within "pure Delphi on Windows" realm. While HTTP service is not main point of mORMot, you'd probably be able to reuse that subpart, and Synopse forum is usually quite responsive.

Comment: As a bonus, mORMot crew are limiting themselves to stay compatible with Delphi7 and FPC and refrain from using all the later syntax enhancements. Subborn heroes :-) You wish "around 10 years from now" and i don't think Delphi would survive 5 years. Also Borland-
I-CG-Embarcadero have a record of dropped features, be it BDE or Bold or CLX. So if you really need 10 years in ahead - then choose FLOSS project with independent yet vivid community that would be able to migrate to Lazarus/FPC when Delphi is dead.

Comment: *But actually, to start a new network-related project, perhaps you'd better looks at some network-oriented library from start ? Like Actors model and Scala Lift or Scala Acca? Sticking with Delphi for new project probably worth it with desktop GUI layer, but other than that would be quite risky investment in both time spent and future maintainance. Best luck to you anyway*

Comment: Main reason to use a Delphi solution is that all the code to service the requests is in Delphi. As far as c10k, I indicated 20 max clients, mostly in a intranet enviroment.

Comment: Any comments on WebBroker ?

Comment: there is also Delphi On Rails, Henri Gourvest project. He is quite talented but not very open man. Usually soft is good but quite scarce on documentation.

Comment: maybe realthinclient.com

Comment: Are you more interested in a REST or a SOAP based architecture?

Comment: I don't know the difference ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WebServices that comes with Delphi and run the ISAPI dll or the cgi exe under Apache or IIS. If you want a standalone solution, application or service, go with RemObjects (this will cost you, but worth the money).

Also, look at this [Building a stand-alone Web service with Indy](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27513)

Comment: RemObjects looks interesting. As it stands now, looks like I'm going with the approach like in the link you provided. With the pure Delphi approach, it will take only a few days to mock up a realistic system and load test it. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I use RemObjects and can recommend it

Answer (score 0):

(This answer assumes you are looking for a SOAP web service framework for Delphi)

If the system needs to be prepared for extensions like [WS-Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) / [WS-Basic Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-I_Basic_Profile) and interoperability with other platforms could be a requirement, I suggest a layered solution:

- expose the web service to the consumers with an existing framework like WCF for the .NET platform or JAX-WS on the Java platform
- implement a simple communication interface (based on JSON or XML messages) between the Delphi side and the web service layer

This decouples the Delphi side from the actual web service layer in a way which allows to support state of the art requirements for the consumers, without reinventing the wheel or 'hacking' around Delphi web service limitations

Comment: Ha,Ha I'm way too experienced to fall for the ditch-Delphi line. TP/Delphi is one of the only general purpose desktop language that hasn't forces its users to re-write over the last quarter century, and at the same time led the industry in innovation.

Comment: Anyhow, off-soap-box, what my question was, for Delphi developers, which of the current options was best for Intranet web services with 20 max connections.

Comment: i guess u're mixing two concept here: WWW and Intranet as "LAN-limited WWW". The dynamic sites that users work through web-browser. And WebServices - that are not exposed to humans , but are a transportation layer betwen server-side and client-side programs (or server-to-server communication). It is not clear whether you wish to make thin native client, or no-clients-all-WWW.

Comment: @Arioch'The as I understand it, it is all about web services, not WWW (HTML pages)

Comment: Server-side and client-side programs. I'll be creating both ends initially (think medical imaging device and PC viewing station), but want capabilities for 3rd parties (like EMR systems) to consume my server-side services easily running on the viewing station. This is a medical device that needs a connectivity solution for eventual 3rd parties in an intranet setting (like a hospital). Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: An EMR interface may very well be accessing html pages we provide within a browser window in their EMR application. Or, consuming web services we provide to transfer images etc.